# Initialize Direct3d when not logged in -or- Automating Windows login

Tags: direct3d, scheduled-tasks

I need to automate a build process that makes use of an app that initializes Direct3d as part of its initialization - even when it never needs to create a window.

I'm trying to automate this task using Windows Task Scheduler (on XP), and I've configured the task scheduler service to allow interaction with the desktop.

The problem I'm running into is that when the user isn't fully logged in, or if the task starts when the user is logged in but the computer is locked, the app in question fails with a message that Direct3d failed to initialize.

Can anyone think of a way around this?  Am I missing some configuration option (in Windows, the task scheduler, or DirectX)?  Is there something I can do before launching this app that will force Direct3d to initialize?  Is there a way to script a windows logon, so the user could be logged in (or the computer unlocked) before launching the app?

Ultimately I could leave the user logged in all the time, and the computer unlocked, but obviously this isn't a desirable solution.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only choice you have is to use autologin and have the machine logged in as that user all the time.

The only other way around this is to use a different tool in your build process that doesn't require Direct3D to initialize.